# systemctl --user doesn't load on startup, even though manual 'start' works well

Tags: linux, services, systemctl

I have systemctl --user set up, that doesn't activate the service on startup.

```
$ cat .config/systemd/user/syncthing.service 
[Unit]
Description=Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for %u
Documentation=man:syncthing(1)
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=STNORESTRART=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
Restart=on-success

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I do `enable` - i get symlinks created:

```
$ systemctl --user reenable syncthing.service 
Removed /home/efim/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/syncthing.service.
Created symlink /home/efim/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/syncthing.service → /home/efim/.config/systemd/user/syncthing.service.
```

But after I log into the system - the service is not running, and there are no errors in the `journalctl`

```
$ systemctl --user status syncthing.service 
● syncthing.service - Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:syncthing(1)
```

I want to set up syncthing on startup.

Initially I used systemctl with `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in `/etc/systemd/system/syncthing@.service`
the process was executed on startup, but failed - maybe due to not being able to access encrypted home directory

I had similar problem as one described here: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/42103

So I tried to create a --user service, but something doesn't work either.
If I do `systemctl --user start syncthing.service` it starts and works, but nothing happens at the startup.

Please help me troubleshoot this further.

Somewhere I've seen advice to check

```
$ systemctl --user list-dependencies default.target 
default.target
● ├─syncthing.service
● ├─ubuntu-report.path
● └─basic.target
●   ├─paths.target
●   ├─sockets.target
●   │ ├─dbus.socket
●   │ ├─dirmngr.socket
●   │ ├─gpg-agent-browser.socket
●   │ ├─gpg-agent-extra.socket
●   │ ├─gpg-agent-ssh.socket
●   │ ├─gpg-agent.socket
●   │ └─snapd.session-agent.socket
●   └─timers.target
```

Here all are green apart from `syncthing.service` - it is grey, looks like "no errors", just "not started"

Comment: What does `journalctl --user -u syncthing.service` show?

Comment: In `journalctl --user -u syncthing.service` I can see only output of the program log from the times I started and stopped service manually with `systemctl --user start` and such

If I do `journalctl --user -u syncthing.service -b` for only logs for current boot it says
`-- No entries --`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a proper solution.
Added command
`systemctl --user start syncthing.service` to my startup hook in XMonad